# handlebars don't operate data output

Tags: json, handlebars.js

My problem is handlebars don't operate Json data output. I don't understand this problem. How can i handle it???

This is my JSON data

```
{ 
    "boardInfo":
    [
        {"no":1,"title":"히히","url":null,"writerNick":"cheolhan","contents":"하하","createdDate":"2016-10-24","createdDate2":"2016-10-24","like":0,"viewCount":19,"email":null,"userNo":"1","categoryNo":2,"category":"스포츠","linkTitle":null,"linkURL":null,"linkDetailUrl":null,"linkImage":null,"linkDesc":null,"userProfilePath":null},
        {"no":2,"title":"히히","url":null,"writerNick":"cheolhan","contents":"하하","createdDate":"2016-10-24","createdDate2":"2016-10-24","like":0,"viewCount":15,"email":null,"userNo":"1","categoryNo":2,"category":"스포츠","linkTitle":null,"linkURL":null,"linkDetailUrl":null,"linkImage":null,"linkDesc":null,"userProfilePath":null},
        {"no":3,"title":"후후","url":null,"writerNick":"cheolhan","contents":"후후","createdDate":"2016-10-24","createdDate2":"2016-10-24","like":0,"viewCount":276,"email":null,"userNo":"1","categoryNo":2,"category":"스포츠","linkTitle":null,"linkURL":null,"linkDetailUrl":null,"linkImage":null,"linkDesc":null,"userProfilePath":null}
    ]
}
```

This is script code

```
var source = $('#liTemplateText').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var data = result.data.boardInfo
data.stringify = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(data)
var boards = template(data);
$("#post_wrapper").append(boards);



{{#each data}}
<li id="each_post_wrap">
  <div id="each_post">
    <div id="user_Nick">
      <img class="user_Nonepht userInfoLink" src="/TeamProject/upload/{{userProfilePath}}" alt="userImg" data-userNo="{{userNo}}" data-userNick="{{writerNick}}">
      <span class="userInfoLink" data-userNo="{{userNo}}" data-userNick="{{writerNick}}">{{writerNick}}</span>
    </div>

  <div class="post_photoWrap titleLink" data-no="{{no}}" data-userNo="{{userNo}}">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="{{linkImage}}" alt="Image File">
    </a>
  </div>


<a class="post_contsWrap">
  <span class="each_post_title titleLink" data-no="{{no}}" data-userNo="{{userNo}}">{{title}}</span>
  <span class="each_post_contents titleLink" data-no="{{no}}" data-userNo="{{userNo}}"><p>{{{contents}}}</p></span>
</a>

<div class="post_ctgWrap">
  <span class="categoryLink" data-ctgNo="{{categoryNo}}">{{category}}</span>
</div>

<div class="post_BtnWrap">
  <div class="post_leftBtn">
    <img class="viewCount" src="/TeamProject/mainpage/mainpage_images/viewCount.png" alt="view">
    <span>{{viewCount}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="post_rightBtn">
    <img class="like_Onclick" src="/TeamProject/mainpage/mainpage_images/likeOnClick.png" alt="like">
    <span>{{like}}</span>
  </div>
<div>
</div>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

This is HTML code

```
<div id="tabs" class="all_post_wrap">
<ul id="post_wrapper" class="tabs-1-contents">


</ul>
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try `{{#each this}}` instead of `{{#each data}}` (assuming you're passing the array to the template directly)

Comment: wow!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

 you are so genius thank you